# How to calculate monthly interest payment from loan?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

My professor put out a piece of text that says this is how you calculate the monthly interest payment on a loan:

[image]

but I can't arrive at the monthly interest payment.

When I type in:

```
(.00417*2000)/((1-(1+.00417) - 24))
```

I get -0.347439...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would expect $n$ to be an exponent

Comment: I still don't get the correct amount. Do you?

Comment: `.00417*2000/(1-1.00417**(-24))` gives me `87.74636227053948` in python

Answer (score 3):

The actual formula is

$$P = \frac{iA}{1-(1+i)^{-n}} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

As shown above, plus as the [J. W. Tanner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/615567/j-w-tanner) and [saulspatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235128/saulspatz) question comments indicated, the "$-n$" at the end of it was poorly formatted and was actually meant to be a power, not subtracting $n$ from the amount. Using $i = .00417$, $n = 24$ and $A = 2000$, \eqref{eq1} gives a monthly payment amount of

$$P = \frac{0.00417 \times 2000}{1 - (1.00417)^{-24}} = \$87.746\ldots \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Although it appears the official answer truncates down to the nearest cent, note that $i = .05/12 = .0041\bar{6}$, with using this more accurate value giving $P = \$87.742\ldots$, so just normal rounding is needed & was likely used. The total payments would be $\$87.74 \times 24 = \$2,105.76$, so the total interest paid over $2$ years would be $\$2,105.76 - \$2,000.00 = \$105.76$.

The Web page [Amortization Calculation Formula](https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/amortization-calculation.html) has the formula of

$$A = P \frac{r(1 + r)^n}{(1 + r)^n - 1} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Here, the $r$ is your $i$, plus the $A$ and $P$ symbols are switched around. When you divide the numerator and denominator by $(1 + r)^n$, you then get your \eqref{eq1} equivalent formula.

Answer (score 2):

Another intuition to find the monthly payment for a loan is to take the present value of all monthly payments and equate it with the loan amount itself, or in formula:

\begin{align}  A = P  \cdot a_{\overline{n}|} \end{align}

in which $A$ is the loan amount, $P$ is the monthly payment,  and 
$ a_{\overline{n}|} $ is just the present value of the annuity formula, which is

\begin{align} a_{\overline{n}|} = \frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n}}}{i} \end{align}

This boils down to

\begin{align} 
P  = \frac{A}{a_{\overline{n}|}}  
   = \frac{A}{\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n}}}{i}} 
   = \frac{iA}{1-\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n}}}
   = \frac{iA}{1-(1+i)^{-n}}
\end{align}

which is the same exact formula as the one your professor gave you.